# Jqgrid for Special characters

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I want to use the datepicker in my jqgrid. I have already tried few things which i have searched on this site, but they did not work. Please help.

I have jqgrid, which is getting data from PHP. Fields includes email & search_date. When the grid loads, it shows the data from the database. But if there is any special character in email, it doesn't show anything in email column. It just shows blank email column.

This is in file.js.

```
function fileview(){

    jQuery("#gridList").jqGrid({ 
        url:'process/viewrecord',
        datatype: "json", 
        colNames:['Email','Search Date'], 
        colModel:[
                  {name:'email',index:'email', width:50, align:"center"},
                  {name:'search_date',index:'search_date', width:17, align:"center"},
                 ],
        rowNum:25, autowidth: true, 
        rowList:[25,50,100,200], 
        mtype: "POST",
        pager: jQuery('#pager1'), 
        sortname: 'id', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        sortorder: "DESC",
        multiselect: true,
        caption:"Details",
        autoencode: true,
        height:'',width:'' }).navGrid('#pager1',{search:false,refresh:false,edit:false,add:false,del:false});
    ReloadGrid('process/viewrecord');
}
```

To show special character in PHP, I have used this & it is working perfectly fine.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

But when it shows the data in Jqgrid, it doesn't do anything.  I have use autoencode: true in code as well.

In phtml file i have used

```
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
```

& then I have called fileview function here

Thanks in advance.